# Backup files to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We are migrating from an on-premises virtual machine to Azure cloud. The virtual machine will eventually be decommissioned and we have many files and folders that we don't want to lose, like old websites and databases, scripts, programs etc.

We use an Azure storage account for storing and retrieving images via blob containers for the live websites.

**Q**: What is the best and most cost effective way to backup large amount of files unused in production, rarely accessed, from an on-premises virtual machine to Azure cloud?

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful to you? If so please mark it as an answer for visibility to help the community.

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT Done. The tool I used is MS Azure Storage Explorer which allows drag-and-drop of large archive files to the blob container and also allows changing the Access tier to Azure Archive Storage by right-clicking the blob > Change Access Tier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Access tier to Azure Archive Storage(if storing data in Blobs) would be your best option. A few notes:

- The Archive storage tier is only available at the blob level and not at the storage account level.
- Archive storage is offline and offers the lowest storage costs but also the highest access costs
- Hot, Cool, and Archive tiers can be set at the object level.

Additional info can be found here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers

Answer (score 0):

recommendation would be to move those unused files to Azure storage archives, which is cost effective and easily accessible when required.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/archive/